# MySQL: Writing a complex query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, join

I have 3 tables. Here I am posting it's database diagram.

[image]

You can download the DB code from here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lk956afaxv147h0/testS.sql?dl=0

Now, using this database and using "only" mysql, I need to do the below work.

1) Given a user ID, it should get a list of all words known by this user, sorted in the revese order from which they were learned. In other words, the most recently learned words will be at the top of the list.

2) You will get a list of all articles which contain this particular word from table "Words"

3) You will scan this list and return all records from table "Article" which contain a maximum of 10 “unknown” words. In other words, if that article contains more than 10 words that do not appear in the user’s vocabulary list (pulled from table "Words_Learned"), then it is excluded from the listing.

4) Then, you move on to the next record in the list from step step 1. You repeat the same process, except you skip any articles that were returned from step 3 or excluded as part of the filtering process in step 3.

To achieve this process, I did the below

```
SELECT `words_learned`.`idwords`,
Words.`idArticle`
FROM words_learned
INNER JOIN Words ON Words.idWords = Words_Learned.`idwords`
WHERE words_learned.userId = 1
ORDER BY Words_Learned.`order` DESC
```

In my query, I have covered point 1 and 2. But what should I need to do in order to cover point 3 and 4?

Comment: 3 can be done with some GROUP BY with post aggregation filtering(HAVING)

Comment: @Mihai: Thanks for the reply. Can you post a clear answer with code please? It would be really helpful to understand.

Comment: Note that using keywords such as `COUNT` and/or reserved words such as `ORDER` as table/column identifiers is a recipe for disaster. COUNT is a particularly odd one because it's not included in MySQL's list of reserved words - but just you try creating a table called COUNT!

Comment: @Mihai: Hello? Can you provide a code sample please?

Comment: I see your "more details with examples", but they describe something entirely different from the original task. Where did you get that original description anyway? It sounds like there is a program using different SQL statments and arrays and loops, and someone said: that should be possible with pure SQL, so they wrote down the steps the original program does, and now this must be converted to SQL (i.e. boiling it down to: what is to be selected finally). However, the details/examples you added now are confusing rather than helping. Have you got them somewhere or did you make them up yourself?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: Thanks for the reply. It came with the original description, I didn't make it by my self. When you consider only the example, can I please know whether it is possible with pure SQL?

Comment: So the new task is: Get 100 articles that have no more then 10 unknown words ordered by "contains last learnt word", "contains 2nd last learnt word", and so on. Yes? That looks tricky but should be possible. I suggest you make this a new request, as it is very different from the original one. (With the original request being "give me all words except for those that are in hard-to-read books", and the new one being "give me 100 easy-to-read books for the last-learnt words". It would be confusing to deal with two different requests and their respective answers in only one stackoverflow question.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: OK, I will open a new question and will let you know. Hope to see you there, your answers are really helpful :)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: New question created. Please be kind enough to assist me here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655410/writing-a-complex-mysql-query

Comment: Hello Sniper. Sorry I am not that fast. I have other things to do, too :-) But I will think of an answer.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: Thanks a lot. Hope to hear from you soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other words: Show all learnt words for which no hard-to-read articles exist. I don't do it quite step by step as suggested. Here is my query:

```
select *
from words_learned
where userid = 1
and not exists
(
  -- word being used in at least one article with too many unknown words
  select *
  from words
  where words.idwords = words_learned.idwords
  and words.idarticle in
  (
    -- articles with more then 10 unknown words
    select w.idarticle
    from words w
    left join words_learned l on l.idwords = w.idwords and l.userid = 1
    group by w.idarticle
    having count(*) - count(l.idwords) > 10
  )
)
order by `order` desc;
```

Here is an SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6de6a/4.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But I think you missed this point - ` In other words, if that article contains more than 10 words that do not appear in the user’s vocabulary list (pulled from table "Words_Learned"), then it is excluded from the listing.`

Comment: Sorry, I think this works! But can you please let me know how I can get the details of `Articles` ? Because the question says `You will scan this list and return all records from table Article`

Comment: I consider the steps as a description on what you need to do to find the words for which no hard-to-read articles exist. One step is to find all articles "which contain a maximum of 10 unknown words". It doesn't mean you must show these articles, you only need to know them in order to get to your final result (or use the description "In other words, if that article contains more than 10 words..." as I do).

Comment: I find the steps a bit misleading, by the way, because the description does not simply say what you want to select (which is how SQL works!). It rather describes a series of activities you would follow when using a programming language instead (select words into an array, take the first record, select the word's articles, ...). This makes it hard to write the SQL (but would make it easy to write a program in C#, Java, Oracle's PL/SQL or whatever programming language is available).

Comment: I will post more detaiks with example now. Please wait.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for *1) Given a user ID, it should get a list of all words known by this user, sorted in the revese order from which they were learned. In other words, the most recently learned words will be at the top of the list.*

```
SELECT ar.content 
FROM article ar INNER JOIN words ws ON ar.idArticle = ws.idArticle 
  INNER JOIN words_learned wl ON wl.idwords = ws.idwords AND wl.userid = @givenID
ORDER BY ar.content DESC
```

Here `@givenID` is provided user ID and to my understanding content will hold value of learnt words

*2) You will get a list of all articles which contain this particular word from table "Words"*

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    article ar 
INNER JOIN 
    words ws 
ON 
    ar.idArticle = ws.idArticle 
AND 
    ws.idwords is like '%pe%'
```

this will select all the words having substring pe like sniper etc . Also you can select  only article content by replacing `*` with `ar.content`

Comment: My question is about point 3 And 4. I have already done what you have provided as the answer.