# Writing a Complex MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, join

Note: you can find my previous question and its answer here - [MySQL: Writing a complex query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629331/mysql-writing-a-complex-query)

---

I have 3 tables.

Table `Words_Learned` contains all the words known by a user, and the order in which the words were learned. It has 3 columns 1) word ID and 2)user  id and 3) order in which the word was learned.

Table `Article` contains the articles. It has 3 columns 1) article ID, 2) unique word count and 3) article contents.

Table `Words` contains a list of all unique words contained in each article. It has 2 columns 1) word ID and 2) article ID

The database diagram is as below/

[image]

You can download the DB code from here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3gr659y5mk05i5w/tests.sql?dl=0

Now, using this database and using "only" mysql, I need to do the below work.

Given a user ID, it should get a list of all words known by this user, sorted in the revese order from which they were learned. In other words, the most recently learned words will be at the top of the list.

Let’s say that a query on a user ID shows that they’ve memorized the following 3 words, and we track the order in which they’ve learned the words. 
Octopus - 3
Dog - 2
Spoon - 1

First we get a list of all articles containing the word Octopus, and then do the calculation using table `Words` on just those articles. Calculation means  if that article contains more than 10 words that do not appear in the user’s vocabulary list (pulled from table `words_learned`), then it is excluded from the listing.

Then, we do a query for all records that contain dog, but DO NOT contain “octopus”

Then, we do a query for all records that contain spoon, but DO NOT contain the words Octopus or Dog

And you keep doing this repetitive process until we’ve found 100 records that meet this criteria.

To achieve this process, I did the below

```
SELECT `words_learned`.`idwords`,
Words.`idArticle`
FROM words_learned
INNER JOIN Words ON Words.idWords = Words_Learned.`idwords`
WHERE words_learned.userId = 1
ORDER BY Words_Learned.`order` DESC
```

In my query, I have covered up to getting the articles, which means to here - `First we get a list of all articles containing the word Octopus, and then do the calculation using table Words on just those articles.`. But what should I need to do in order to cover the rest?

**Update**

Here is a phudocode for better understanding.

```
Do while articles found < 100
{
 for each ($X as known words, in order that those words were learned)
 {
  Select all articles that contain the word $X, where the 1) article has not been included in any previous loops, and 2)where the count of "unknown" words is less than 10. 

  Keep these articles in order. 
 }
}
```

Comment: @Strawberry: Please have a look at that question, its selected answer, and its comments before taking a decision as a duplicate.

Comment: The diagram is wrong by the way. Words can be learned by more than one user and a learned word can be in more than one book. Additionally the table name "words" is not a good choice at all, because this is not the table that contains words, but the link from word to article. So there should better be a table words(idwords pk, word) and another table articlewords(idarticle, idwords). At last naming should be consistent, i.e. table names *either* describe the table (words, articles) *or* the record (word, article). (Consequently: *either* idwords and idarticles *or* idword and idarticle.)

Comment: And I just looked at your CREATE TABLE statements in Dropbox. Making idwords the primary key in words, each word can only be in *one* article, which makes no sense.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: I noticed your point few minutes back and I fixed it. I will upload it now.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner:done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be tempted to have a sub query that gets all the words a person has learned and join that against itself, with the words GROUP_CONCAT together along with a count. So giving:-

```
Octopus, NULL, 0
Dog, "Octopus", 1
Spoon, "Octopus,Dog", 2
```

So the sub query would be something like:-

```
SELECT sub0.idwords, GROUP_CONCAT(sub1.idwords) AS excl_words, COUNT(sub1.idwords) AS older_words_cnt
FROM words_learned sub0
LEFT OUTER JOIN words_learned sub1
ON sub0.userId = sub1.userId
AND sub0.order_learned < sub1.order_learned
WHERE sub0.userId = 1
GROUP BY sub0.idwords
```

giving

```
idwords    excl_words    older_words_cnt
1          NULL          0
2          1             1
3          1,2           2
```

Then join the results of this against the other tables, checking for articles where the main idwords matches but none of the others are found.

Something like this (although not tested as no test data):-

```
SELECT sub_words.idwords, words_inc.idArticle
(
    SELECT sub0.idwords, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(sub1.idwords), ',', 10) AS excl_words, COUNT(sub1.idwords) AS older_words_cnt
    FROM words_learned sub0
    LEFT OUTER JOIN words_learned sub1
    ON sub0.userId = sub1.userId
    AND sub0.order_learned < sub1.order_learned
    WHERE sub0.userId = 1
    GROUP BY sub0.idwords
) sub_words
INNER JOIN words words_inc
ON sub_words.idwords = words_inc.idwords
LEFT OUTER JOIN words words_exc
ON words_inc.idArticle = words_exc.idArticle
AND FIND_IN_SET(words_exc.idwords, sub_words.excl_words)
WHERE words_exc.idwords IS NULL
ORDER BY older_words_cnt
LIMIT 100
```

EDIT - updated to exclude articles with more than 10 words that are not already learned.

```
SELECT sub_words.idwords, words_inc.idArticle,
sub2.idArticle, sub2.count, sub2.content
FROM
(
    SELECT sub0.idwords, GROUP_CONCAT(sub1.idwords) AS excl_words, COUNT(sub1.idwords) AS older_words_cnt
    FROM words_learned sub0
    LEFT OUTER JOIN words_learned sub1
    ON sub0.userId = sub1.userId
    AND sub0.order_learned < sub1.order_learned
    WHERE sub0.userId = 1
    GROUP BY sub0.idwords
) sub_words 
INNER JOIN words words_inc
ON sub_words.idwords = words_inc.idwords
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT a.idArticle, a.count, a.content, SUM(IF(c.idwords_learned IS NULL, 1, 0)) AS unlearned_words_count
    FROM Article a
    INNER JOIN words b
    ON a.idArticle = b.idArticle
    LEFT OUTER JOIN words_learned c
    ON b.idwords = c.idwords
    AND c.userId = 1
    GROUP BY a.idArticle, a.count, a.content
    HAVING unlearned_words_count < 10
) sub2
ON words_inc.idArticle = sub2.idArticle
LEFT OUTER JOIN words words_exc
ON words_inc.idArticle = words_exc.idArticle
AND FIND_IN_SET(words_exc.idwords, sub_words.excl_words)
WHERE words_exc.idwords IS NULL
ORDER BY older_words_cnt
LIMIT 100
```

EDIT - attempt at commenting the above query:-

This just selects the columns

```
SELECT sub_words.idwords, words_inc.idArticle,
sub2.idArticle, sub2.count, sub2.content
FROM
```

This sub query gets each of the words learnt, along with a comma separated list of the words with a larger order_learned. This is for a particular user id

```
(
    SELECT sub0.idwords, GROUP_CONCAT(sub1.idwords) AS excl_words, COUNT(sub1.idwords) AS older_words_cnt
    FROM words_learned sub0
    LEFT OUTER JOIN words_learned sub1
    ON sub0.userId = sub1.userId
    AND sub0.order_learned < sub1.order_learned
    WHERE sub0.userId = 1
    GROUP BY sub0.idwords
) sub_words
```

This is just to get the articles the words (ie, the words learned from the above sub query) are used in

```
INNER JOIN words words_inc
ON sub_words.idwords = words_inc.idwords
```

This sub query gets the articles which have a less than 10 words in them that are not yet learnt by the particular user.

```
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT a.idArticle, a.count, a.content, SUM(IF(c.idwords_learned IS NULL, 1, 0)) AS unlearned_words_count
    FROM Article a
    INNER JOIN words b
    ON a.idArticle = b.idArticle
    LEFT OUTER JOIN words_learned c
    ON b.idwords = c.idwords
    AND c.userId = 1
    GROUP BY a.idArticle, a.count, a.content
    HAVING unlearned_words_count < 10
) sub2
ON words_inc.idArticle = sub2.idArticle
```

This join is to find articles that have words in the comma separted list from the 1st sub query (ie words with a larger order_learned). This is done as a LEFT OUTER JOIN as I want to exclude any words that are found (this is done in the WHERE clause by checking for NULL)

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN words words_exc
ON words_inc.idArticle = words_exc.idArticle
AND FIND_IN_SET(words_exc.idwords, sub_words.excl_words)
WHERE words_exc.idwords IS NULL
ORDER BY older_words_cnt
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Hi, I think you missed my update? which has the restriction of 100 articles and 10 max unknown words per article?

Comment: The limit is easy. The limit of 10 words can be done by using SUBSTRING_INDEX on the excl_words to get everything up to the 10th comma.

Comment: Could you post up the table declares and some test data please (in a format that can just be cut and pasted to the tables).

Comment: Hi, this generates an error - `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT sub0.idwords, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(sub1.idwords), ',', 10) excl_w' at line 3 `

Comment: Looks like a simple typo (forgot to put AS) now fixed. But without test data I can't really test it to check for things like this or for results.

Comment: Issue is somewhere out of the sub query.

Comment: Managed to fix the issue. But it is not excluding articles with more than 10 unknown words. here is the tables with data in it - https://www.dropbox.com/s/3gr659y5mk05i5w/tests.sql?dl=0

Comment: I had misunderstood what you required. I thought you meant just exclude the first 10 words after a required one. I will have a look into it.

Comment: Added an extra suggestion

Comment: wow, complex thing! Can I please know whether this follow this condition? - `Then, we do a query for all records that contain dog, but DO NOT contain “octopus”

Then, we do a query for all records that contain spoon, but DO NOT contain the words Octopus or Dog`

Comment: Yes it does do that (or should). That was the main function of the original query. The first sub query gets each word, and then a list of the words to exclude for that word. The FIND_IN_SET is used on a LEFT OUTER JOIN to check if a non wanted word is found.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. I have marked your answer as the solution. Anyway, can you please put some comments in your code so I can understand your logic better?

Comment: I have tried to add a few comments to a split up version of the query.

Comment: Hi, pardon me but from client comments it was rejected as incorrect. I have created a new question, mind having a look please? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26857304/complex-mysql-query-is-giving-incorrect-results

Answer (score 1):

So, I think this is it. You want to get the "best" 100 articles, where "best" means the later a word learnt it contains the better it is. So I look for each article's last learnt word (the max(words_learned.order) per article). Then I show the article IDs in that order and stop at 100.

```
select w.idarticle, max(l.`order`)
from words w
join words_learned l on l.idwords = w.idwords and l.userid = 123
group by w.idarticle
order by max(l.`order`) desc
limit 100;
```

You have edited your request. You want to limit the results to articles that contain no more then ten unknown words. In order to do so you must now outer-join the learnt words, so you can count the unknown words (i.e. the outer-joined records). Use HAVING to remove undesired articles from the list.

```
select w.idarticle, max(l.`order`)
from words w
left join words_learned l on l.idwords = w.idwords and l.iduser = 123
group by w.idarticle
having sum(l.idwords is null) <= 10 and max(l.`order`) is not null
order by max(l.`order`) desc
limit 100;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think you missed my edit which I made as soon as I asked for your help, there was a SO error here which might cause the delay in edit posting. Pardon me me for the update, can you have a look at it please?

Comment: Ah, there is that easy/hard article thing again. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I do have a question, your code do not consider this right? - `Then, we do a query for all records that contain dog, but DO NOT contain “octopus”

Then, we do a query for all records that contain spoon, but DO NOT contain the words Octopus or Dog`

Comment: Not directly. Rather than selecting those with "octopus" (order 3) and *then* those with "spoon" (order 2) that don't have "octopus" and so on, I select *all* articles and find their latest last learnt word. So I get a list of all articles where the last learnt word is "octopus" plus articles where the last learnt word is not "octopus" but "spoon" and so on. So the difference is: I don't do it iteratively, but in one step.

Comment: interesting. I will get back to you by tomorrow, good night! Hope to see you tomorrow!

Comment: I've posted another answer. This one here is wrong. (Starting with: I'm selecting articles rather than words.) I don't delete it though, because it shows how to find easy/hard-to-read articles.

Answer (score 1):

I've read that question again and notice it is much more complicated.

First of all you want to show words. And whether you show a word depends on that word and all before-learned words (and the articles they appear in).

So with these words learned:

```
word      order
Octopus   3
Dog       2
Spoon     1 (i.e.first learned)
```

And these articles:

```
article  contains Octopus   contains Dog   contains spoon   unknown words
A             yes               yes             yes              5
B             yes               yes             no              11
C             yes               no              yes             15
D             no                yes             yes              2
E             no                yes             no               0
F             no                no              yes              8
G             no                no              no               3
H             no                no              no              20
```

You ...

- check "Octupus" and dismiss it because of article B or C.
- check "Dog" and keep it, because articles D and E are okay and B must be ignored (as it contains "Octopus").
- check "Spoon" and keep it, article F is okay and C must be ignored (as it contains "Octopus").

So you show "Dog" and "Spoon" and not "Octopus". And if there were not only two matches, but thousand, you would show the first 100 and then stop.

Given this algorithm, we can conclude:

- As long as too few word were learned, no results will be shown at all.
- At some point enough words will be learned to find articles with less than 11 unknown words. The last-learned words will probably not be shown (as "Octopus" in the example), because there are still many articles with too many unknown words. But earlier words will be shown (because the last-learned words filter away the hard-to-read articles).
- Then some day most of the words will be learned. Then it is the last-learned words that will be shown.

The query:

```
select idwords
from words_learned
where userid = 123
and not exists
(
  select w.idarticle
  from words w
  left join words_learned l on l.idwords = w.idwords and l.userid = 123
  group by w.idarticle
  having sum(l.idwords is null) > 10 and max(l.`order`) = words_learned.`order`
)
order by `order` desc
limit 100;
```

Here is an SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19bf8/1.

Comment: Thanks, you are great. However as I mentioned before, we have to show the "Article" information, not idword

Comment: Quote: "I need to do the below work. Given a user ID, it should get a list of all **words** known by this user, sorted in the revese order from which they were learned". Anyhow, you've got one answer on how to show articles and another on how to show words. So make your choice or combine or change them as needed :-)

Comment: Hi, pardon me but from client comments it was rejected all the answers here. I have created a new question, mind having a look please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26857304/complex-mysql-query-is-giving-incorrect-results