# Complex MySQL query is giving incorrect results

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, indexing

Note: You can find the previous question and its answer here. A deep testing on it proved the previous answer is incorrect: [Writing a Complex MySQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655410/writing-a-complex-mysql-query)

---

I have 3 tables.

Table `Words_Learned` contains all the words known by a user, and the order in which the words were learned. It has 3 columns 1) word ID and 2)user  id and 3) order in which the word was learned.

Table `Article` contains the articles. It has 3 columns 1) article ID, 2) unique word count and 3) article contents.

Table `Words` contains a list of all unique words contained in each article. It has 2 columns 1) word ID and 2) article ID

The database diagram is as below/

[image]

Now, using this database and using "only" mysql, I need to do the below work.

Given a user ID, it should get a list of all words known by this user, sorted in the revese order from which they were learned. In other words, the most recently learned words will be at the top of the list.

Let’s say that a query on a user ID shows that they’ve memorized the following 3 words, and we track the order in which they’ve learned the words. 
Octopus - 3
Dog - 2
Spoon - 1

First we get a list of all articles containing the word Octopus, and then do the calculation using table `Words` on just those articles. Calculation means  if that article contains more than 10 words that do not appear in the user’s vocabulary list (pulled from table `words_learned`), then it is excluded from the listing.

Then, we do a query for all records that contain dog, but DO NOT contain “octopus”

Then, we do a query for all records that contain spoon, but DO NOT contain the words Octopus or Dog

And you keep doing this repetitive process until we’ve found 100 records that meet this criteria.

To achieve this process, I did the below (Please visit the SQLFiddle link to see the table structures, test data and my query)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48dae/1

In my query, you can see the generated results and they are invalid. But on a "Proper Query", the result should be,

```
Level 1
Level 1
Level 1
Level 2
Level 2
Level 2
Level 3
Level 3
```

Here is a phudocode for better understanding.

```
Do while articles found < 100
{
 for each ($X as known words, in order that those words were learned)
 {
  Select all articles that contain the word $X, where the 1) article has not been included in any previous loops, and 2)where the count of "unknown" words is less than 10. 

  Keep these articles in order. 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from (
    select a.idArticle, a.content, max(`order`) max_order
    from words_learned wl
    join words w on w.idwords = wl.idwords
    join article a on a.idArticle = w.idArticle
    where wl.userId = 4
    group by a.idArticle
) a
left join (
    select count(*) unknown_count, w2.idArticle from words w2
    left join words_learned wl2 on wl2.idwords = w2.idwords
    and wl2.userId =  4
    where wl2.idwords is null
    group by w2.idArticle
) unknown_counts on unknown_counts.idArticle = a.idArticle
where unknown_count is null or unknown_count < 10
order by max_order desc
limit 100
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6944b/9

The first derived table selects unique articles a given user knows one or more words from as well as the maximum `order` value of those words. The maximum order value is used to sort the final results so that articles containing high order words appear first.

The second derived table counts the number of words a given user doesn't know for each article. This table is used to exclude any articles that contain 10 or more words the user doesn't know.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Seems like my results (which I mentioned as incorrect) are similar to yours, isn't it? hmmmm....

Comment: @Sniper your fiddle refers to userId 4 and 1. Is that a mistake?

Comment: It seems to be! wow, your edited code gives the exact answer!! Pls give me few hours to do do the deep test!!